# Pandas not renaming column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rename

I have a DataFrame using pandas with column names that I am looking to rename; however, the output is proving to be unsuccessful.

**Code**

```
    def custom_parse(self, response):
        #scraping a website with a list of txt files and downloading it locally
        links = response.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'.txt')]/@href").getall()
        for link in links:
            local_path = self.download_file('https://www2.census.gov/econ/bps/County/' + link)
            df = pd.read_csv(local_path, sep='\t', dtype=str)
            df.columns = [col.lower().strip().replace(" ", "_") for col in df.columns]
            df = df.rename(columns={
                 'survey': 'survey_date'
            })
            df = df.fillna('')
            for k, row in df.iterrows():
                yield dict(row)
```

FYI, I am downloading a list of text files and reading the data into a DataFrame. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify:

1.) Are you intentionally using ```df``` for all links without saving another reference to it? If so, you'll only have a reference to the last ```link```

2.) Are you intentionally not returning the ```DataFrame``` from the method? If so you'll have no references to any of the modified ```DataFrame```s.

If the above two points are intentional, then how are you seeing that the columns aren't being modified?

Comment: you could add `assert 'survey' in df.columns` above rename, just to make sure you are using the exact column name. otherwise, could you post a [complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (not just a function definition), as well as the behavior you're seeing and what you're expecting?